# Lowest Total Distance Possible Parking Lot Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Today I got to the final round of three algorithmic coding interview sessions and got stumped pretty hard by the last question that was asked of me. Rather than let it go and move on with my life, I really want to see what a solution might look like. I'll do my best to describe it:

You have a set of cars and parking lots.

You know the distances from each car to each parking lot and the parking lot capacities.

How would you make sure each car gets to a parking lot with a vacancy so that all cars travel the least amount of total distance possible?

A small example might be:

```
distance_car1_to_lot1 = 1
distance_car1_to_lot2 = 10
distance_car2_to_lot1 = 2
distance_car2_to_lot2 = 100
lot1_capacity = 1
lot2_capacity = 1
```

You can see here that if you were to take `car1` and put it into `lot1` and `car2` into `lot2`, the distance traveled of all cars would be `101`.

Rather than doing that, taking `car1` to `lot2` and `car2` to `lot1` would result in a total travel distance of `12`.

How might you solve this, assuming there could be more cars and more parking lots than listed above.

My language of choice for the entire interview process was Javascript but I suppose you can do what suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this problem as a graph where the vertices are the cars and the parking lots and the edge weights are the travel distances. This graph is a complete bipartite weighted graph. You can find the optimal assignments of cars to parking lots by using the Hungarian algorithm (Kuhn-Munkres) as explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCaD34z--bY

To deal with parking lot capacities you can split the parking lot nodes into multiple nodes with capacity 1. For example, if parking Lot 2 has a capacity of 3, you can replace it with Lot 2a, 2b and 2c.
You might also need to add dummy nodes to balance the number of cars and parking lots. For example if you have 3 car nodes and 4 parking lot nodes, you can add 1 dummy car node with edge weights 0 to all parking lot nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is about all I'm willing to do right now. Good luck!

```js
function distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, feet = false){
  let p = 0.017453292519943295, c = Math.cos;
    let r = 12742000*Math.asin(Math.sqrt(0.5-c((lat1-lat2)*p)/2+c(lat2*p)*c(lat1*p)*(1-c((lng1-lng2)*p))/2));
    if(feet)r *= 1/0.3048;
    return r
}
function Vehicle(color, year, make, model, lat = null, lng = null){
  this.color = color; this.year = year; this.make = make; this.model = model; this.lat = lat; this.lng = lng;
  this.distanceTo = (latLng, feet = false)=>{
    return distance(this.lat, this.lng, latLng.lat, latLng.lng, feet);
  }
}
function Lot(lat, lng, capacity){
  this.lat = lat; this.lng = lng; this.capacity = capacity;
  this.vehicles = [];
  this.addVehicle = vehicle=>{
    if(this.vehicles.length < this.capacity){
      vehicle.lat = this.lat; vehicle.lng = this.lng; this.vehicles.push(vehicle);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.removeVehicle = vehicle=>{
    const v = this.vehicles, x = v.indexOf(vehicle);
    if(x !== -1)v.splice(x, 1);
    return this;
  }
  this.distanceTo = (latLng, feet = false)=>{
    return distance(this.lat, this.lng, latLng.lat, latLng.lng, feet);
  }
}
function sortDistances(distances, feet = false){
  const d = [...distances], r = [], sortIt = (a, b)=>Object.values(a)[0]-Object.values(b)[0];
  let n, a;
  for(let lot of d){
    n = -1; a = [];
    for(let l of d){
      n++;
      if(l !== lot)a.push({[n]:lot.distanceTo(l, feet)});
    }
    a.sort(sortIt); r.push(a);
  }
  return r;
}
const lot1 = new Lot(47.581148063351534, -122.24032639373426, 1);
const lot2 = new Lot(47.583444521820496, -122.2447443008423, 1);
const lot3 = new Lot(47.583544521820333, -122.2447543008222, 35);
const vehicle1 = new Vehicle('yellow', 1979, 'Ford', 'Pinto');
const vehicle2 = new Vehicle('red', 2020, 'Ferrari', '812 Superfast');
lot1.addVehicle(vehicle1); lot2.addVehicle(vehicle2);
const lots = [lot1, lot2, lot3]; // so you can get the lots by index later
const d = sortDistances(lots);
console.log(d); // an Array of Arrays of Objects with lots indexes as keys and meters as values
```